# C# DispatcherTimer Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I have an issue with the WPF Timer.

Here's my code  :

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

As you can see the interval is 1 minute.
But when i start my timer, after 1 hour i have a 10 seconde delay. So, i guess it the treatment of my code who make this delay, but i really need a fix timer, without any shift.

Sorry for your eyes  !!

Comment: First of all, that interval is 1 second, and not 1 minute.
Second, try the constructor where you specify the priority `DispatcherTimer a = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send)`

Comment: Mhm, its even worst, now after 1 loop, 3 second delay

Comment: Why are you using a dispatcher timer if you need a fix timer?

Comment: Try creating a program where all you do is this timer.  Then, if you still have the problem, post your code here.

Comment: @DiSiZ - You understand that this is an "interval" meaning when the last handler of the tick completes then the next interval starts? So if the handlers take 0.25 seconds to process then each successive start is 1.25 seconds if the interval is set to 1 second.

Comment: I should use a normal timer Nekeniehl ?

Comment: Ive done it Neil, 0 delay when the program is empty, with just the timer

Comment: I was thinking using this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx#Fields
Look's more accurate

Answer (score 0):

The delay is caused by the WPF GUI thread, which runs all WPF code, like rendering and the `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event. The rendering has a higher priority than a `DispatcherTimer` with default priority. So when at the time your `Tick` is supposed to run also some rendering is needed, the rendering gets executed first and delays your Tick by x milliseconds. This is not too bad, but unfortunately these delays can accumulate over time, if you leave the `DispatcherTimer.Interval` constant. You can improve the precision of the `DispatcherTimer` by shortening the `DispatcherTimer.Interval` for every x milliseconds delay like this:

```
const int constantInterval = 100;//milliseconds

private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var nowMilliseconds = (int)now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
  var timerInterval = constantInterval - 
   nowMilliseconds%constantInterval + 5;//5: sometimes the tick comes few millisecs early
  timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timerInterval);
```

For a more detail explanation see my article on CodeProject: [Improving the WPF DispatcherTimer Precision](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5323994/Improving-the-WPF-DispatcherTimer-Precision)